# Secure previously created API without token based authentication

Tags: node.js, security, express

I am asked to maintain security for web-API(will be clarified in a minute), but the problem is I am not allowed to make any structural changes, that is using any kind of token-based or user-based authentication is not possible. I offered to use CORS, but both mobile and web application use the same service, so this is not an option as well. The bottom line is I want to make the service secure with minimal changes.

Comment: "secure" is a very broad term, in what way do you want to make it secure, and from what?

Comment: basically, I do not want someone else to use my endpoints for their own applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a secret apiKey, and then for every api call you take the entire body of the request, add "- apiKey" at the end, and run it trough a sha1 encryption (or simmilar one way enryption) then you put the result as "checksum" in the header

on the serverend you do the same thing, take the body of the request, add "- apiKey" and run it trough the same oneway encryption, and hten compare the result to the checksum in the header of the resuest. if the strings matches you allow it, otherwise block the call.

this is not too much to implement, and it doesnt really change anything about the structure, but if this is too much "changes" so you are not allowed, then the only other option is using firewall to only allow certain ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

The token approach is advisable as there isn't much structural change. You need to add a middleware, where all the API calls hit, and there you perform a token validation. Orrr you could use cookies to secure your endpoints